# Pulling data from Facebook Graph API 2.0 Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm working in Koala with Facebook's Graph API 2.0. Now when you call user_friends using

```
<% @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends") %>
```

You should get an object that contains something like the following:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Friend 1", 
      "id": "xxxxx"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Friend 2", 
      "id": "xxxx"
    },
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/...."
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": number of friends
  }
}
```

My question is how do I pull the information from summary. I tried printing this in my ruby app but I only saw the following:

```
[]
```

Does that mean the return was nil? I tried to call @friends.summary, but that didn't work

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

Also make sure you authorized yourself with the user_friends permission, of course.

Comment: Yes, but it now also returns the summary part as well according to the latest changelog. How do I ensure I've authorized myself with the user_friends permission? I've added 'user_friends' to my Koala scope and it is one of the default permissions for the app right?

Comment: yeah, you don´t need to go through the review process with it. can you get the access token somehow? you can test it in the debugger and see if the user_friends permission is set up correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I just printed out my permissions using `<% permissions = @graph.get_connections('me','permissions') %>` and user_friends isn't listed. Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: in that case, you either did not authorize the user correctly or you did not authorize him correctly with the user_friends permission...

Comment: Is there anyway to tell? Here is what i have listed for permissions in my scope under devise.rb: `equire "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret'] {:scope => 'user_friends, email, public_profile' , :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}`